# AT USSD command with Siemens TC35 working depending on the country

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim-card, ussd, telecommunication

I tried to perform a USSD request with AT command.
My USSD command is working for a SIM from a country A but not working from a SIM from a country B.

With country A:

```
00:14:57|        At:DEBUG:  sendCommand: AT+CUSD=1,"#111#",15
00:14:57|        At:DEBUG:  waitResponse: AT+CUSD=1,"#111#",15OK
00:14:57|        At:DEBUG:  waitResponse: result = <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10a1b3e00>
00:15:02|        At:DEBUG:  waitResponse: +CUSD: 1,"Welcome my service",15> 
00:15:02|        At:DEBUG:  waitResponse: result = <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x109c22918>
```

With country B:

```
00:14:57|        At:DEBUG:  sendCommand: AT+CUSD=1,"#111#",15
00:14:57|        At:DEBUG:  waitResponse: AT+CUSD=1,"#111#",15
--> ERROR
```

Do you know what can be the issue?

EDIT: 
If I active the error message: AT+CMEE=2, I get:

```
+CME ERROR: ss not executed
```

EDIT2:
If I send the short code in PDU format I get the CME Error after a OK:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"23198D3602"

OK

+CME ERROR: ss not executed
```

If I send the short code in text mode I get the CME Error after a Ok also:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"#144#",15

OK

+CME ERROR: ss not executed
```

I tried this SIM in a Huawei key and it's working. I think I missed a parameter in the TC35 configuration.

I compared the configuration:
TC35:

```
AT+CSCS=?
+CSCS: ("GSM","UCS2")
AT+CSCS?
+CSCS: "GSM"
AT+CSMP?
+CSMP: 17,167,0,0
```

Huawei:

```
AT+CSCS=?
+CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2")
AT+CSCS?
+CSCS: "IRA"
AT+CSMP?
+CSMP: ,,0,0
```

If I put the CSCS at GSM for the Huawei it's still working.

Both key have the AT+CMGF=0 configuration.

EDIT 07/10/2013:

Please find below the different configurations between the Huawei (working with the SIM) and the TC35 (not working withe the sim).

HUAWEI:

```
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,2,"20801",2

AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,5

AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 9,99

AT&V
&C: 2; &D: 2; &F: 0; E: 1; L: 0; M: 0; Q: 0; V: 1; X: 0; Z: 0; S0: 0;
S2: 43; S3: 13; S4: 10; S5: 8; S6: 2; S7: 50; S8: 2; S9: 6; S10: 14;
S11: 95; S30: 0; S103: 1; S104: 1; +FCLASS: 0; +ICF: 3,3; +IFC: 2,2;
+IPR: 115200; +DR: 0; +DS: 0,0,2048,6; +WS46: 12; +CBST: 0,0,1;
+CRLP: (61,61,48,6,0),(61,61,48,6,1),(240,240,52,6,2);
+CV120: 1,1,1,0,0,0; +CHSN: 0,0,0,0; +CSSN: 0,0; +CREG: 0; +CGREG: 0;
+CFUN:; +CSCS: "IRA"; +CSTA: 129; +CR: 0; +CRC: 0; +CMEE: 2; +CGDCONT: (1,"IP","internet","0.0.0.0",0,0)
; +CGDSCONT: ; +CGTFT: ; +CGEQREQ: (1,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(2,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(3,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(4,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(5,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(6,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(7,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(8,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(9,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(10,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(11,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(12,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(13,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(14,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(15,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0),(16,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,"0E0","0E0",3,0,0)
; +CGEQMIN: ; +CGQREQ: ; +CGQMIN: ; ; +CGEREP: 0,0; +CGCLASS: "A";
+CGSMS: 1; +CSMS: 0; +CMGF: 0; +CSAS: 0; +CRES: 0;
+CSCA: "+22376000000",145; +CSMP: ,,0,0; +CSDH: 0; +CSCB: 0,"","";
+FDD: 0; +FAR: 0; +FCL: 0; +FIT: 0,0; +ES: ,,; +ESA: 0,,,,0,0,255,;
+CMOD: 0; +CVHU: 1; ; +CPIN: ........,........; +CMEC: 0,0,0; +CKPD: 1,1;
+CIND: 0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0; +CMER: 0,0,0,0,0;  +CGATT: 1; +CGACT: 0;
+CPBS: "SM"; +CPMS: "SM","SM","SM"; +CNMI: 0,0,0,0,0; +CMMS: 2; +FTS: 0;
+FRS: 0; +FTH: 3; +FRH: 3; +FTM: 96; +FRM: 96; +CCUG: 0,0,0;
+COPS: 0,2,""; +CUSD: 1; +CAOC: 1; +CCWA: 0; +CCLK: ""; +CLVL: 4;
+CMUT: 0; +CPOL: 0,2,"",0,0,0; +CPLS: 0; +CTZR: 0; +CTZU: 0; +CLIP: 0;
+COLP: 0; +CDIP: 0; +CLIR: 0; ^PORTSEL: 0; ^CPIN: ........,........;
^ATRECORD: 0; ^FREQLOCK: 11796860,0; ^GLASTERR: 1; ^CVOICE: 0;
^DDSETEX: 0; ^CMSR: 0; ; ^AUTHDATA: 1,0,"",""; ^CRPN: 0,""; ^DNSP: ;
^DNSS: ; ^WPDST: 1;  ^WPDOM: 0; ^WPDFR: 65536,1; ^WPQOS: 255,50;
^WNICT: 0; ; . 

AT+GCAP
+GCAP: +CGSM,+DS,+ES
```

**TC35:**

```
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"Orange F"

AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,5

AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 17,99

AT&V
ACTIVE PROFILE:
E1 Q0 V1 X4 &C1 &D2 &S0 \Q0 
S0:000 S3:013 S4:010 S5:008 S6:000 S7:060 S8:000 S10:002 S18:000 
+CBST: 7,0,1 
+CRLP: 61,61,78,6 
+CR: 0 
+FCLASS: 0 
+CRC: 0
+CMGF: 0
+CNMI: 0,0,0,0,1
+ILRR: 0
+IPR: 0
+CMEE: 0
^SMGO: 0,1
+CSMS: 0,1,1,1
^SACM: 0,"000000","000000"
^SCKS: 0,1
+CREG: 0,5
+CLIP: 0,2
+CAOC: 0
+COPS: 0,0,"Orange F"

AT+GCAP
+GCAP: +CGSM,+FCLASS
```

TC35 is a SIM300 model. I would like to know if this modem is compatible with 64k sim.
For information the SIM is working on Huawei E173 and Huawei E176 key.

EDIT 08/10/2013:
I tried a SIM32k from the same country and it is working with the TC35 modem. So question is now quite simple: Is it possible to use a 64k sim with a TC35 modem

Thank you

Comment: The likeliest explanation is the #111# is not supported on operator B's network.  Have you checked that out?

Comment: The USSD short code is reachable from a basic phone. I got this error for all the USSD short codes I know working on this network. I am not able to find documentation on this error. the description is not explicit for me. Maybe the network of this country support another kind of encoding etc. Maybe should I read/write some parameter from/to the SIM?

Comment: It seems that the SIM not working is a 64k sim. Maybe should I do some configuration related to the PCM rate communication?

Comment: Confirmation. This is working with a 32k SIM but not with a 64k SIM. Any suggestion to support 64k SIM on TC35 Siemens modem?

Comment: Hi Julio, I'm still reading this question with interest, just don't know that much about different SIMs.  The 32K and 64K are just the amount of memory on the SIM though - are the 2 SIMs from the same manufacturer?

Comment: The worksheet for your modem (published 2001) says "The baseband processor has an integrated SIM interface compatible with the ISO 7816-3 IC Card standard"   I tried to find this standard on the ISO website, without success.  But I'm wondering if there have been other changes as well as increasing the memory on the SIM.  Or, if your modem is actually that old?

Comment: The storage size of SIM cards is not just for contacts and sms. It also stores ciphers for GSM encryption/decryption, Operator connection defaults from the operator who provided the SIM card and some other stuff. This has been known to influence connection speeds when switching from say a 32k to a 128k (the norm these days). Primarily due to operator specific information stored on the SIM card.

Comment: Looking at the original question I am wondering whether it's a combination of problems. Something to do with the SIM card size and the fact they are roaming.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problems with MC35i. Some cards work with CUSD and DCS response 72, some card work with CUSD but DCS response must be 15 only, some card just dont work with CUSD. In last case may help AT-command ATD:

```
-->AT+CUSD=1,"*100#",15
<--OK
...
<--+CME ERROR: ss not executed
-->ATD"*100#;
<--OK
...
<--+CUSD: 2,"UTF16BE",72
```

Also you can get same problem with performing of chain USSD commands. In this case may to help adding space before symbol `<CTRL+Z>`:

```
-->ATD"*111*38#;
<--OK
...
<--+CUSD: 1,"UTF16BE(menu with list of command)",72
<--> 
-->command<CTRL+Z>
<--OK
...
<--+CME ERROR: ss not executed
-->ATD"*111*38#;
<--OK
...
<--+CUSD: 1,"UTF16BE(menu with list of command)",72
<--> 
-->command <CTRL+Z>
<--OK
...
<--+CUSD: 2,"UTF16BE",72
```